# How to use multiple data-id in Oracle APEX?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, oracle-apex

I set data-id in ID column html expression, like:
data-id=&ID. - and it works.
But, how I can set data-id=&LAST_NAME. in same report and use that data-id in JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically you add a class to the same html tag as the data attribute, for example `class="myclass"`. Then add a dynamic action on click of jquery selector `.myclass`. In javascript then reference the value of the `data-id` with the expression `this.triggeringElement.dataset['id']` - this could be used in an action of type "Set Value" to set a page item value to the `data-id` attribute of a clicked row.

Note that it doesn't have to be "data-id". It's possible to use "data-whateveryouwant". So you would have a "data-empno", a "data-ename" and a "data-deptno", all in the same html tag. Also explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly. I added data-* and it works. But, when I tried to use same HTML to another column with data-* instead of data-id it didn't work?

Comment: sorry I don't understand what you mean. Did you literally user "data-asterisk" with an "asterisk" or some other value. What does "didn't work" mean ?

Comment: I have ID column which is HTML expression and contain HTML including data-id and data-column2 and it works. When I tried to copy HTML and paste in another column of same type and just replace data-id with data-column2 it didn't work( I can't set item value ).

Comment: If it's in another column you also need to change the class - did you do that ? If this doesn't work I suggest you file another question. Answering in comments is not obvious

Answer (score 1):

When you use:  example

```
 01. use the class="myClassName"
 02. add dynamic action on click of jquery selector .myClassName
 03. set the page item value of multiple data attribute with js expression

$(this.triggeringElement).data('id');

$(this.triggeringElement).data('last_name');
```